# Microsoft Dynamics CRM and App Proxy

Tags: c#, azure, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I am trying to connect to an on-premises instance of Microsoft Dynamics CRM protected by a firewall and that has been exposed externally via Azure AD Application Proxy with pre-authentication enabled.

Thus, given how App Proxy works (fetch an access token to be used in subsequent requests by passing it as a bearer token in an HTTP header) I am encountering an issue with the Dynamics XRM SDK when trying to create a service configuration.

```
var serviceConfiguration = ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration<IOrganizationService>(
    new System.Uri(*app proxy url*),
    true,
    GetType().Assembly
);
```

The SDK requires an Organization Service WSDL that is served without any authentication, however when using App Proxy this can only be served by passing in the bearer token header and so the code above throws an exception instead. I can not find a way around this, without potentially using reflection and even that would require significant effort and introduces a lot of scope for error.